# ASP.NET System.IO.File.Open("C:\TEST.TXT", System.IO.FileMode.Open); ERROR FILE NOT FOUND? LOCAL:

Tags: asp.net, file, client, .net

Dumb question.. is this c# code intended to read local client files?

System.IO.FileStream content = System.IO.File.Open("c:\test.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open);

It gives me error ***FILE NOT FOUND***

I'm running Windows 7 and IE 8.

Answer (score 2):

Having \ by itself means an escape character.
You need to either use @ or double \

```
System.IO.FileStream content = System.IO.File.Open(@"c:\test.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open);
or
System.IO.FileStream content = System.IO.File.Open("c:\\test.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open);
```

If both fails..Check your NTFS permissions on the file.

Comment: Thanks.  yes I need to escape the backslashes.. but still getting file not found. this file must be on the server right? not my client.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot @ before "

```
System.IO.FileStream content = System.IO.File.Open(@"c:\test.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open);
```

ofcourse you can do in this way:

```
System.IO.FileStream content = System.IO.File.Open("c:\\test.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open);
```